# Allow following during private beta

Tags: feature-request, area-51, notifications, private-beta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The evolution of a Proposal seems designed to drive people away](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57081/the-evolution-of-a-proposal-seems-designed-to-drive-people-away)

I recently wanted to ask a question about photography. I looked on the Area51 and saw that the [Photography Proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1265) was still in a private beta. I want to be notified whenever it goes into a public beta. If you are following a proposal then you will be notified, so I decided to go to the definition tab and try to follow it. Following is disabled though.

Therefore I propose one of the following so that I can be notified when it goes into public beta(by email)

1. A "notify me when in public beta" feature or
2. Ability to follow a proposal when in private beta

Comment: Also, the exact opposite please: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55841/cant-unfollow-a-proposal-in-beta

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57081/the-evolution-of-a-proposal-seems-designed-to-drive-people-away