# If I can't commit during private beta, don't show me the commit link!

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, private-beta, commitment

I'm interested in the [UI-related stack exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5728). Apparently, I'm [not allowed to commit to it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57081/the-evolution-of-a-proposal-seems-designed-to-drive-people-away) now that it's in private beta.
I'd like to be able to be notified when it goes into public beta, but that's not my main point. **If I can't commit now, you should say that, rather than providing a link at the bottom of the page that does nothing!**

Comment: I totally agree. When clicking on the “Commit to this proposal!” link I initially thought something was broken. Also, it's not a good practice to use Javascript within the `href` attribute, use proper URLs instead, so your interface degrades unobtrusively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed now. The commit link is removed if the proposal is closed or in beta.